CSS Grid for an unpredictable gallery
Can anyone think of a way to predictably not leave gaps in a GRID gallery, with unpredictable content? I know that I could just force it into even columns and then distribute the content across those columns leaving all the weird whitespace at the bottom, but I really wanting to use multi-column spanning elements. The only thing I can think of to do is to get the backend to organise the images (these elements would be images) by protrait v landscape and use maths to calculate a good order that they present. That will work, but I am hoping there is someone stronger than me in CSS to solve it for me? 1x1, 2x1, 1x2 images are absolutely fine, no need to make it more clever than that. Thanks in advance.


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid2-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 0;
}

.grid2-gallery .item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.grid2-gallery .item.landscape {
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.grid2-gallery .item.portrait {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.grid2-gallery .item.square {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}
<section class="grid2-gallery">
  <div class="item square" style="background-color:blue;">
    Some caption about image 0
  </div>
  <div class="item portrait" style="background-color:red;">
    Some caption about image 1
  </div>
  <div class="item landscape" style="background-color:green;">
    Some caption about image 2
  </div>
  <div class="item portrait" style="background-color:blue;">
    Some caption about image 3
  </div>
  <div class="item portrait" style="background-color:red;">
    Some caption about image 4
  </div>
  <div class="item square" style="background-color:blue;">
    Some caption about image 5
  </div>
  <div class="item landscape" style="background-color:green;">
    Some caption about image 6
  </div>
  <div class="item square" style="background-color:blue;">
    Some caption about image 7
  </div>
</section>



Here is my (poor) attempt: https://codepen.io/bruceclothier/pen/gOVgqMo
could put images as background images in div.item, or could put image inside div.item. that part is not important, it is the layout that is. I don't knwow if i will get a portrait, landscape or square image, and in what order...

The easiest way would be to use grid-auto-flow: dense; on the grid-container. That will place the grid-cards to fit spacings:


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid2-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  gap: 0;
}

.grid2-gallery .item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.grid2-gallery .item.landscape {
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.grid2-gallery .item.portrait {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.grid2-gallery .item.square {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}
<section class="grid2-gallery">
  <div class="item square" style="background-color:blue;">
    Some caption about image 0
  </div>
  <div class="item portrait" style="background-color:red;">
    Some caption about image 1
  </div>
  <div class="item landscape" style="background-color:green;">
    Some caption about image 2
  </div>
  <div class="item portrait" style="background-color:blue;">
    Some caption about image 3
  </div>
  <div class="item portrait" style="background-color:red;">
    Some caption about image 4
  </div>
  <div class="item square" style="background-color:blue;">
    Some caption about image 5
  </div>
  <div class="item landscape" style="background-color:green;">
    Some caption about image 6
  </div>
  <div class="item square" style="background-color:blue;">
    Some caption about image 7
  </div>
</section>



